# Disabled User - Joomla plugin and now can't login

Tags: plugins, joomla

Hope someone can help.

I have accidental disabled the user - joomla plugin that allows the login of both front and back end. Consequently I can no longer log in to the back end to enable it again.

Is there any way I can do this through ftp in a file or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be addressed by logging in to phpMyAdmin, going to the #__extensions table, and then setting the enabled field of the plg_authentication_joomla plugin to 1 in joomla V.3

Answer (score 0):

You could enable plugin via database (phpmyadmin).

You have to locate it in `#__extensions` table and set `enabled` value to 1.

Hope this helps